# Problemas com "or" em C++

Tags: c, c++, operadores

Preciso fazer um algoritmo que recebe 3 números diferentes, e, se receber números repetidos, informa uma mensagem de erro.

Meu programa está todo funcionando corretamente, mas quando vou colocar a tal linha para avisar do erro tento usar `Or` e não dá certo. Segue o que estou digitando

```
if (z==x) or (y==z) or (x==y);
    cout << "\nErro. Os valores devem ser diferentes. Tente novamente: \n" << endl;
```

Mesmo que tenha um modo mais fácil do que `or`, vocês poderiam, por gentileza me dizer como funciona a inserção do `or` em C++ ?

Segundo o Code::Blocks, o programa espera uma expressão primária antes do `or`.

Comment: Você não precisa fazer isto agora ou se não achar que deve mas se a resposta lhe atendeu bem você pode aceitá-la como correto. E pode votar em todos os posts do site que ajudaram de alguma forma. Veja o [tour].

Comment: na verdade, seu problema não é exatamente com o operador OR; e sim, como você escreveu o if. Se fizesse if (z==x or y == z or x == y) cout.... nao iria ter problemas.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A sintaxe preferencial do `or` em C++ é `||` apesar de serem sinônimos.

Além disto tinha um `;` que estava encerrando o `if` e não executando da forma como parece ser seu desejo. A mensagem não estava fazendo parte do bloco condicional.

Também há problema com os parênteses. Um único par deve conter toda a condição. Você até poderia colocar parênteses extras nas sub-expressões mas eles são totalmente desnecessários.

Então sua linha ficaria:

```
if (z==x || y==z || x==y)
    cout << "\nErro. Os valores devem ser diferentes. Tente novamente: \n" << endl;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Operator/AndOr.cpp).

Chaves poderiam ser recomendadas para encapsular o bloco mesmo tendo apenas uma linha. Isto evita alguns erros por descuido. Mesmo que opte por não usar chaves seria interessante colocar o bloco que deverá ser executado condicionalmente em uma nova linha com indentação como demostrado acima.

Comment: +1 por apresentar sobre as chaves

Comment: Nota: `or` e `||` são sinônimos.

Answer (score 4):

O operador lógico *OR* no C++ é o `||`.

```
if(z == x || y == z || x == y) {
  cout << "\nErro. Os valores devem ser diferentes. Tente novamente: \n" << endl;
}
```

Você também está adicionando um `;` depois do `if`. Isto vai fazer com que esta linha seja encerrada ali e o cout irá sempre imprimir a mensagem, independente do resultado da avaliação do `if`.

Comment: `or` também funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Se for usar C++ 11/14, você poderá usar o or( || ) e o and( && ) normalmente se quiser.

Comment: Dá uma olhada às outras respostas que já há aqui. Se achares que vale a pena submeter mais uma resposta ainda explica por favor melhor então. Até já. (ah, e bemvindo!)