# Problemas com if e condições

Tags: c, c++, if

Estou fazendo um código que recebe três valores e os ordena do maior para o menor. Como condição, quando os números são repetidos, uma mensagem de erro é exibida e o programa deve encerrar. Se os números são distintos, ele pula esse `if` e segue para a ordenação propriamente dita.
Utilizei a seguinte linha de código:

```
if (z==x or y==z or x==y)
    cout << "\nErro. Os valores devem ser diferentes. Tente novamente: \n" << endl;
  //restante do código
```

Porém, mesmo que os números sejam diferentes, o programa sempre exibe a mensagem

> "Erro. Os valores devem ser diferentes. Tente novamente:"

Gostaria que ela fosse exibida somente quando houvesse o erro, e que nesse caso, o programa encerrasse ali mesmo, e não continuasse, pois isso também está ocorrendo.

Abaixo segue o código completo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int x,y,z,ft,sd,th;

int main()
{
    cout << "Digite 3 valores reais e diferenteees: \n";
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    cin >> z;

    if (z==y or x==z or x==y)
        cout << "\nErro. Os valores devem ser diferentes de 0 e nao repetidos. Tente novamente: \n" << endl;

    if (x>y and x>z)
        ft=x;
        else if (x>y and x<z)
            sd=x;
            else if (x>z and x<y)
            sd=x;
                else if (x<y and x<z)
                    th=x;

    if (y>x and y>z)
        ft=y;
        else if (y<x and y>z)
            sd=y;
            else if (y<z and y>x)
                sd=y;
                else if (y<x and y<z)
                th=y;

    if (z>x and z>y)
        ft=z;
        else if (z<x and z>y)
            sd=z;
            else if (z<y and z>x)
                sd=z;
                else if (z<x and z<y)
                    th=z;

    cout << "\nOs valores ordenados sao: \n" << endl;
    cout << "Valor mais alto: " << ft<< endl;
    cout << "Valor intermediario: " << sd<< endl;
    cout << "Valor mais baixo: " << th<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Está confuso, principalmente porque você não está colocando seu código real. Mas na verdade parece que você ignorou as respostas dadas a você na outra pergunta. Se insistir fazer errado não vai funcionar. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53261/problemas-com-or-em-c Você deve [edit] a pergunta e colocar seu código para analisarmos, leia isto http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Como você disse 'estar pegando a manha do SOpt', vou sugerir que você leia o [TOUR]. E o link que o @bigown postou também é bastante interessante para você se inteirar de como funciona o SOpt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reformulei seu programa para resolver o problema e dar uma organizada para ele ficar mais legível. Recomendo prestar bastante atenção nas mudanças.

Não tenho certeza se seu código está fazendo o que você deseja mas eu fiz testes com alguns valores e parece dar resultados consistentes e resolve o problema principal que você estava reclamando. Organizei a indentação e coloquei a declaração das variáveis dentro da função já que não tem nenhuma razão para elas estarem fora.

Variáveis devem ser declaradas no escopo mais interno possível, neste caso é a função. Do jeito que estava as variáveis funcionariam como variáveis "globais" que não costuma ser uma boa ideia. Claro que neste caso restrito não causa nenhum problema mas em códigos mais complexos causa. Então já vai aprendendo o certo desde já.

Fiz uma mudança colocando um laço para o código repetir se os dados digitados não estão de acordo com a necessidade. Esta forma de usar um `continue` condicional e um `break` incondicional não é a ideal mas não quis modificar a sua lógica, como você está aprendendo talvez tivesse dificuldade de entender. Basicamente este código dentro do bloco `while` vai executar uma vez e sair por causa do `break`. A não ser que ele entre no `if`, aí o `continue` nele fará o `break` ser pulado, e vai repetir o laço até que não entre mais no `if`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x, y, z, ft, sd, th;
    while(true) {
        cout << "Digite 3 valores reais e diferentes: \n";
        cin >> x;
        cin >> y;
        cin >> z;

        if (z == y || x == z || x == y) {
            cout << "\nErro. Os valores devem ser diferentes de 0 e nao repetidos. Tente novamente: \n" << endl;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    if (x > y && x > z)
        ft = x;
    else if (x > y && x < z)
        sd = x;
    else if (x > z && x < y)
        sd = x;
    else if (x < y && x < z)
        th = x;

    if (y > x && y > z)
        ft = y;
    else if (y < x && y > z)
        sd = y;
    else if (y < z && y > x)
        sd = y;
    else if (y < x && y < z)
        th = y;

    if (z > x && z > y)
        ft = z;
    else if (z < x && z > y)
        sd = z;
    else if (z < y && z > x)
        sd = z;
    else if (z < x && z < y)
        th = z;

    cout << "\nOs valores ordenados sao: \n" << endl;
    cout << "Valor mais alto: " << ft<< endl;
    cout << "Valor intermediario: " << sd<< endl;
    cout << "Valor mais baixo: " << th<< endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/TeI8Ze). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dmztqpoc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/ControlFlux/Conditional.c).

Note que no ideone eu coloquei chaves nos `if`s. Elas não são necessárias neste caso mas é recomendável usar sempre para evitar confusões quando precisa.

Comment: Aqui não deu certo. Apresentou o mesmo erro de continuar com os if's subsequentes mesmo se os números forem repetidos, e neste, caso, ainda gera valores gigantescos na ordenação. Poderia ser meu IDE?

Comment: Acredito que não seja problema do IDE. É difícil dizer ao certo, você viu que está funcionando, certo? Você tentou copiar e colar este código aqui e compilá-lo ao invés de alterar o seu? Nem que seja só para testar.

Comment: @MaximilianoMeyer tinha uma coisa que eu não tinha percebido, eu mudei agora veja se resolve o que você quer. Depois se você evoluir e tiver outras dúvidas, poste aqui para a gente ir te ajudando na novas dúvidas.

Comment: Show de bola. Funcionando. Vou aceitar a resposta. Abraço

Comment: Agora foi ^^ obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Se voce incluir estas duas linhas antes da instrução 'main', seu código vai compilar sem erros:

```
#define or ||
#define and &&
```

Comment: Isalon, não deu certo, retornou a seguinte mensagem:              Error: "and" cannot be used as a macro name as it an operator in c++

Comment: Isto é altamente não recomendável. Ele está aprendendo. Outras pessoas sem entender o contexto virão aqui e achar que devem fazer isto de verdade. Sinceramente estou pensando em negativar a resposta porque ela induz ao erro. Ela funciona mas ninguém deveria fazer isto a não ser como brincadeira.

Comment: @Bigown O que me surpreende é o voto positivo. Respeito e defendo o direito do lsalamon postar o que quiser (e arcar com as consequências naturais), mas o voto me preocupa mais que a resposta.

Comment: Afff, fui enganado =(

Comment: @Maximiliano Meyer, não leve em consideração os comentários acima. Coloquei teu código no Visual Studio 2013 e compila perfeitamente com a minha alteração. Acredite.

Comment: Huum. Ok, acredito sim. Tô aqui pra aprender, não pra julgar. Obrigado então.