# Precedência de operadores com ponteiros

Tags: c, algoritmo, ponteiro, operadores

Tendo, por exemplo, as seguintes instruções:

```
int i=10, j=20; 
int *pti, *ptj; 
pti = &i; 
ptj = &j;
```

Qual o significado de

```
j = pti == ptj;
```

e de

```
i = pti || ptj;
```

?

Além disso, eu li que a soma a subtração entre ponteiros `(pti+pj` ou `pti-pj`, por exemplo) resulta em inteiros. Por que isso acontece?

Comment: `pti+ptj` dá erro de compilação.

Comment: Quem quiser brincar com isso: https://ideone.com/6pAjfC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que você está querendo saber o significado dos operadores.

`==` é o operador de igualdade, então está verificado se os ponteiros são iguais e é óbvio que o resultado será 0 (falso) já que ele aponta para dados em variáveis diferentes. Seria 1 apenas se ambos fossem iguais, ou seja, pegaria o mesmo endereço e isto ocorreria se os dois ponteiros apontassem para a mesma variável, neste caso.

`||` é o operador lógico de `OU`, ou seja, ele testa se ambos são verdadeiros, no caso só daria falso se ambos fossem nulos, já que para este operador dar 0 (falso) os dois endereços teriam que ser 0.

Obviamente o resultado está sendo armazenado nas variáveis originais. O código só tem utilidade de demonstração.

Se a dúvida sobre precedência ainda persiste tem uma [tabela nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40180/101). Nota-se que o operador de atribuição tem uma das mais baixas precedências e é quase certo que ele será executado por último em expressões comuns (apenas a separação de expressões tem prioridade mais baixa para permitir múltiplas declarações.

Veja mais na [pergunta sobre o OR do C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53261/problemas-com-or-em-c) ou [nessa outra sobre PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47886/101) mas o princípio é o mesmo e ainda [sobre JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38016/101).

O Jorge B. já falou sobre a soma de ponteiros ser é impossível no comentário.